# GIF preloading then starting animation on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gif

I have an animated gif which is placed around 120vh down the page. I want this gif to start loading as the page starts loading as its a few MB but then I don't want the animation to trigger until the user scrolls down to it.

What is the best way to achieve this? I have read a few posts about waypoints and lazy loading but am still unclear to the best way to achieve this.

Comment: The best way to achieve this is indeed using waypoints and lazy loading ;-)

Comment: You can also just place a static image there, same size, mimicking the first frame of the loader. That way it looks paused until you replace it with the animated .gif